# Change Graphql query so it will display each product on a separate row

Tags: google-sheets, graphql, shopify-api

Tl;Dr: I need to change my Graphql query so it will display each product on a separate row with it's 'rateProvider' (or shipping rate) data in columns next to it.

---

I'm retrieving Shopify API data using the query below in Google Sheets using The API Connector add-on and following the instructions here for GraphQL: https://mixedanalytics.com/knowledge-base/access-shopify-data-in-google-sheets/

The query retrieves Shopify products and their delivery profile. But all products are being displayed in a single row based on their delivery profile? For instance, if 10 products are in delivery profile ($100 Shipping) then all 10 products for that delivery profile would appear in a single row together with their delivery profile data like first example below.

But I want each product to be displayed on separate rows with the delivery profile data in the columns beside it like the second example below *I am also not sure of how to setup the proper pagination for this query to pull 'all products'.

Example 1:
product #1 | product #2 | deliveryProfile ($100 shipping)
product #1 | product #2 | deliveryProfile ($50 shipping)

Example: 2:
product #1 | deliveryProfile ($100 shipping)
product #2 | deliveryProfile ($100 shipping)
product #1 | deliveryProfile ($50 shipping)
product #2 | deliveryProfile  ($50 shipping)

```
query ($cursor: String) {
  deliveryProfiles (first: 5) {
    edges {
      node {
        profileItems (first: 5, after: $cursor) {
          edges {
           cursor
            node {
              product {
                id
                handle
              }
              variants (first: 5) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    title
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        profileLocationGroups {
          locationGroupZones(first: 5) {
            edges {
              node {
                methodDefinitions(first: 5) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      rateProvider {
                        ... on DeliveryRateDefinition {
                          id
                          price {
                            amount
                          }
                        }
                        ... on DeliveryParticipant {
                          id
                          fixedFee {
                            amount
                            currencyCode
                          }
                          percentageOfRateFee
                          participantServices {
                            active
                            name
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look, are you able post a copy of the sheet? Also, have you looked into the possibility of using Apps Script for this?

Comment: Are you just pasting the above code into a cell? How are you trying to assign the result of the query to the cells?

Comment: Yes, I am pasting the above code into a single cell. Also, I'm using a Google Sheets API Connector add-on and following the instructions here for GraphQL: https://mixedanalytics.com/knowledge-base/access-shopify-data-in-google-sheets/

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for?  Are you looking for a better Graphql query? Are you looking for a formula or a script to change the add-on result after it's added to the spreadsheet?

Comment: I need to change my Graphql query so it will display each product on a separate row with it's 'rateProvider' (or shipping rate) data in columns next to it.

Comment: I was told it's not possible to change this query to meet my requirements? Here is what I was told "....due to the nature of graphQL you are not able to manipulate this structure enough to get uniform column names."

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** If you are using the API Connector (Add-On) for Google Sheets to import data from Shopify AND you are using a GraphQL Query you have to go into the API Connector's [Output Options] menu and change Report style to [Compact] to display the individual records on their own rows.